# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError was thrown. The getter 'type' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

Hi Im currently developing mobile app with Flutter. My program has two type of user so I need to condition the user based on type from data. So while checking the user data, a NoSuchMethodError was thrown stating the getter was called on null on red screen for a second before proceed. But the object is not null. I dont know what else to do. Can anyone help me :( The 2s exception annoys me...

```
final profile = Provider.of<Profile>(context);

if (profile.type == null) {
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
  );
} else {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: profile.type ? SessionWrapperTutor() : SessionWrapperTutee(), //here the problem occur
  );
```

this is the error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomeWrapper(dirty, dependencies: [InheritedProvider<Profile>], state: _HomeWrapperState#91be8):

The getter 'type' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: type

The relevant error-causing widget was HomeWrapper
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

#0      Object.noSuchMethod
#1      _HomeWrapperState.build
#2      StatefulElement.build
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
```

Comment: Thank youuu very much! I cant .isEmpty because the profile is object. But found solution already. Thank you for advise! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception is telling you, you are calling `type` on null, meaning at some point `profile` is null and you are trying to call `type` on it. You just need to check if `profile` is not null before trying to use it

Comment: bro if she calling profile on null so she showing progress indicator

Comment: No, there is an if condition: `if (profile.type == null)` but `profile` is null at some point apparently so obviously it's throwing an exception

Comment: You still don't get it, the issue is not from `type`, the issue is `profile` being null, you can't call `.type` on something that is null, just read the exception message..

Comment: OMG it worked! Yeay! Yes I need to check if profile is null and return circular thing. Finally the red screen is goneeee. Thank you very much! :''''')